# How to catch exception with WidgetTester if 'EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY' in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I want to verify that the widget can throw an exception.

I tried this code:

```dart
  testWidgets('it fails other widgets if', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // expect(() async {
    //   await tester.pumpWidget(WidgetThatThrowUnimplementedError());
    // }, throwsA(isA<UnimplementedError>()));

      try {
        await tester.pumpWidget(WidgetThatThrowUnimplementedError());
        fail('Exception was not thrown');
      } catch (e) {
        expect(e, isA<UnimplementedError>());
        return;
      }
  });
```

But got: "`EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY`" and

```
  Actual: TestFailure:<Exception was not thrown>
   Which: is not an instance of 'UnimplementedError'
```

How to catch `UnimplementedError`?

Comment: Your test cannot catch it because, as the message indicated, the error was *already caught* by the Flutter widgets library...

Comment: See the documentation for [`WidgetTester.pumpWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpWidget.html) which specifically tells you (with an example) to use [`TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.takeException`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestWidgetsFlutterBinding/takeException.html) for cases like this.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it:  
```
    await tester.pumpWidget(WidgetThatThrowUnimplementedError());
    final e = TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.instance.takeException();
    expect(e, isA<UnimplementedError>());
```